# Angular 2 - Passing a url with @Input

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm making a component for a dropdown select menu. I want to be able to load the options for the menu dynamically. I was initially thinking of doing this by using @Input to pass in the url of the desired controller method to fetch the data. Here's what I have so far (simplified):

```
export class DropdownInput {
    // List of options for the dropdown to have
    public options: InputOption[];

    // Url for controller method to get options
    @Input() optionSrc: string; 

    // Get list of options on construction
    constructor(http: Http) {
        http.get(this.optionSrc).subscribe(result => {
            this.options = result.json();
        });
    }
}
```

And I was trying to use this dropdown component like this:

```
<dropdown-input 
    [optionSrc]="/api/LogViewer/GetOpts">
</dropdown-input
```

But I am getting the error: "Parser Error: Unexpected token / at column 1 in [/api/LogViewer/GetOpts]".  I've also tried doing it as "'/api/LogViewer/GetOpts'", but this fails with the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse ()". I get the same error when putting the url in a variable in the parent class, and binding to that.

Is this possible to do? Or should I try a different way of achieving my goal altogether?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you are passing a static string you should do following,

```
<dropdown-input 
    [optionSrc]="'/api/LogViewer/GetOpts'">
</dropdown-input>
```

if constructor doens't work for you then you should consider to use **`ngOnInit()`** like,

```
ngOnInit() {
        http.get(this.optionSrc).subscribe(result => {
            this.options = result;                    
            //<<<### changed this line... as suggested by StefanSvrkota
        });
}
```

Comment: I had tried this without the spaces beforehand, and just now with the spaces and unfortunately I'm still getting the error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)".  Where is the <anonymous> coming from, is this because I'm subscribing to the result of this http.get?

Comment: @csy9 I believe you are getting the error because you are trying to parse `result` to json while in fact it isn't json. Try with `this.options = result;` and let us know if it works. Or just `console.log(result);` and see what you get then.

Comment: @StefanSvrkota YOU GOT A POINT.

Comment: @StefanSvrkota Good call.  By replacing the "this.options = result.json()" with "console.log(result)", I can see that I am returning some random html garbage, and the xhr network call is null instead of being a valid controller.

Comment: @StefanSvrkota What's weird though is manually hardcoding in the url into the get request works fine. Could it be that since the http.get call is in the constructor, optionSrc is undefined or something? Putting "console.log(this.optionSrc) displays the url correctly, though....

Comment: @csy9 That is exactly what is happening. Input values are not populated until `ngOnInit` is called. The constructor is the first method fired here so your input value is undefined.

Comment: @StefanSvrkota micronyks' edit solved it basically.  Had the constructor just set up the http service, and ngOnInit make the call. I think what was happening was that I put the "console.log(this.optionSrc)" after the http.get request, and optionSrc was getting initialized halfway through the constructor, so it was undefined during the get but appeared to be alright later.